# How to calculate total liabilities?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

> Columbia Company began the current year with 450,000 in assets and 250,000 in total stockholders equity. During the year Columbia earned 85,000 and distributed 10,000 as dividends. Assets at year end were 500,000. Liabilities were what?

I know the answer is 175,000 but I can't figure out what numbers to plug into "Assets = Liabilities + Stockholders' Equity" in order to learn how to do it for my upcoming test.

I have plugged every number I can think of into that equation and cannot seem to come up with 175,000. I have tried 500,000-450,000=50,000. Then 50,000+85,000=135,000. But no matter what I try I can't come up with 175,000.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, at least your thoughts, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Comment: I have just tried plugging and chugging every number I can think of into that equation and tried to come up with 175,000 with no luck.

Comment: Seriously try to use this site all the time and I get nothing but down votes for my questions. Or someone trying to tell me to explain what I did. Never anyone actually helping to teach me how to do a problem. Isn't that what this site is about? I understand some people use people here to do their homework but I mean I already have the answer here. I just want to learn how to do it. Not sure why some people downvote my questions for no reason.

Comment: @Tom -- maybe people downvote you because you post finance101 questions on a math forum and call it algebra-precalculus, which it is certainly not.

Comment: @uniquesolution Last time I checked plugging numbers into a formula and solving for "x" is algebra. I even provided the formula so I don't know what you're fussing about. The big scary finance words that could have been replaced with anything to turn this into a normal word problem?

Comment: @Tom the down votes usually are because people expects some effort  before asking (when I started to ask here at MSE it happened the same to me because I did not know the rules...), at least saying what you have tried is fine I think. In your case you edited the question to add more information, that is a good step. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assets = Stockholders Equity + Total Liabilities

(500 000) = (250 000 + 85 000 - 10 000) + Total Liabilities

Total Liabilities = 175 000

Is it supposed to be this way? Because 10 000 is paid off as dividends, so you only earned 75 000 instead of 85 000.